# How to make the current working directory be highlighted in color?

Tags: command-line, 20.04, permissions, sudo

my ns-3 is installed inside the source folder i.e., home/my_username/source/ns-3.39, when I try to ls inside the ns-3.39 directory, it gives:
**ls: cannot open directory '.': Permission denied**
So I have to su root and then enter the ns-3.39 directory to use it.
The problem is, in doing that, the pwd does not get highlighted while in the former situation, the pwd is highlighted in green. How can I make the su root solution also show the pwd in highlighted mode?

[without su root](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YmgS.png) 
[with su root](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PS8Nz.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show colored prompt all you need to do is change the `PS1` variable. Run

```
export PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ ' # from default bashrc
```

this would set colored. You can add it at the bottom of `/root/.bashrc` so that bash starts with the above value of `PS1`.

[0] https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Bash/Prompt_customization